# Meteor content not displaying

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am having issues with either Flow Router or my template level subscriptions but the data is not being rendered on the page.

Just incase the issue isn't what I have pasted here I have included a link to the entire github repo: https://github.com/adjohnston/checkr-meteor

lib/routes.js

```
listRoutes.route('/:slug', {
  name: 'list',

  subscriptions: function (params) {
    this.register('singleList', Meteor.subscribe('singleList', params.slug));
  },

  action: function () {
    FlowLayout.render('mainLayout', {
      main: 'list'
    });
  }
});
```

server/publication/lists.js

```
Meteor.publish('singleList', function (slug) {
  return Lists.find({slug: slug});
});
```

client/lists/list.js

```
Template.list.helpers({
  singleList: function () {
    return Lists.find();
  }
});
```

client/lists/list.html

```
<template name="list">

  {{#if isSubReady}}
    {{#with singleList}}

      <h2>Name: {{name}}</h2>

    {{/with}}
  {{/if}}

</template>
```

## Solution

Change returns Lists.find() to Lists.findOne() since the publication 'singleList' is only returning a single result.

client/lists/list.js

```
Template.list.helpers({
  singleList: function () {
    return Lists.findOne();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your `singleList` helper to a `findOne`:

```
Template.list.helpers({
  singleList: function () {
    var slug = FlowRouter.getParam("slug");
    return Lists.findOne({slug: slug});
  }
});
```

Right now you are trying to display the `name` property of a cursor, which is what `find()` returns. You also don't need `{{#with singleList}}` in your handlebars.

Comment: So the issue was caused by using find() in my helper instead of simply using findOne(). I have stuck with using #with so I don't need to prefix all the attributes with singleList. Also is there a benefit to using the params in the helper over using the params in the publish?

Comment: They are serving different purposes. You'd use it in your publish to control what data you will need on the client. You may have reasons to publish multiple lists to a route but only display one at a time in this particular helper. It will depend on your application needs.